# Module compiled with Swift 5.2.4 cannot be imported by the Swift 5.1.2 compiler

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I try to build my app (I'm a client not a developer of this app) but when I try to build in my Xcode 12.2.1 I have this error.

anyone here can help me to fix it?
I really need to publish my app (i await for a very long time)

Comment: Looks like you need to use Xcode 11.5 https://swift.org/download/#releases

Comment: Xcode 12.2.1? Xcode 12 still in beta